# How can I run and make changes to a cloned app on my local machine?

Tags: node.js

I am relatively new to development and currently need to run a client's app on my local machine in order to make and test the changes. I cloned the app from the github repo, but have been unable to run the app on my local machine.

I have used the npm install, then the npm start command, but it gives me this error

`"> node dist/server.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
throw err;
^`

`Error: Cannot find module '********\dist\server.js' at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12) at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: []`
}

`Node.js v19.0.1"` 
I don't know how to proceed with this. Please help

Comment: Is there maybe an "npm build" command that you have to start before running? check the "scripts" object in the package.json

Comment: There is no npm build command

Comment: You have to build the project. `dist` is a common folder name for build artifacts. `npm run` tries to run the built project, but the project wasn't built. `dist/server` seems to be unrelated to React and frontend.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You Are Missing environment variables. Get Them From The Client.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).